# Pages won't load - only on my computer

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, internal-server-error

Created a asp.net 5 project with another team member and works on everyone's computer but mine. I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error and the web page is blank.[image: Internal Server Error]

I thought maybe I was missing a .net version but when downloading .NET Framework 4.6 it says ".NET Framework 4.6 or a later update is already installed on this computer."
If someone could point me in the right direction it would be a lot of help! Thanks!
[image]

Comment: ASP.NET 5 and .NET Framework 4.6 are *NOT* the same thing.  You need to have the DNX core (I think that's what it is now) installed.

Comment: Indeed... Asp.Net 5 is now called "Asp.Net Core 1.0", so you'll need the core bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem! I had a dependency issue in my project.json file.
"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess": "12.1.2400"
"FluentNHibernate": "2.0.3"
"NHibernate.Caches.SysCache": "4.0.0.4000"
These packages didn't support dnx 5.0 so they couldn't be in the default dependencies section. They needed to go under dnx451 -> dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

The error code is very general in that some error happened in your code that stopped the execution of the webpage.

If you are running the webpage in debug mode from Visual Studio on your computer, VS should have stopped on the line of code containing the error.

If, for some reason, Visual Studio does not stop on the error, you can also look in Windows Logs -> Application.  It should appear as an Asp.Net Warning with details regarding the error.

See Log #3: 
http://blog.leansentry.com/the-server-logs-you-need-to-know-to-fix-any-iis-aspnet-error/

Comment: When I look at the logs I don't get any errors or warnings, and Visual Studio doesn't break. There is one more developer that is having the same problem, but it is working for the other three. Could I be missing an update or download that is required to run asp.net 5 applications?

Comment: It looks like you found an "HttpPlatformHandler cannot be found" error in the log, based on your screenshot.  This post about Asp.Net5 looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527012/cannot-launch-asp-net-5-web-app-in-iis-express